# How can I make sure that the footer will always be on the bottom of the last page when printing out?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am new to web designing, I have searched for an answer and tried almost everything I could find but couldn't get what I want. Ok, I know there are many solutions for sticking a footer to the bottom of the page in a browser. But my question is not about how the footer looks like in the browser, but in the print out. My layout is something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="content">
     <table>
       more divs... more content...
     </table>
      <table>
        more divs... more content...
     </table>
     ....
  </div>
  <footer>
     <table>
      ....
     </table>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And please notice my content is dynamic, it can be long or short based on user input. In browser I dont have any problems, the footer is at the bottom of the content. But in print outs I want this footer to be at the bottom of the last page (and I want this to work mainly only in IE browsers. IE 7, 8 and 9). So if the content is long, and it goes to 3 print out pages, the footer should appear only on the bottom of the last page. Please tell me how I can get this done? Most online solutions like sticky footer just dont work in the print out when the content is long...They stick to the bottom of the content in the print out as you can see in print previews. I will really appreciate any help. Simple css solutions are better, but if nothing else works out I am ready to try js, PHP as well even though I am a beginner.

Comment: make a PDF. A web page is not a great way to force a print design

Comment: Even though I agree with you, they dont want to go to pdf when they print. They want to have less possible number of steps to get the print out.

Comment: So add it as <link rel="alternate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok its been a while but the answer might help someone. Like I said in the question I was required to make it work only in IE. . It works for IE7 8 and 9. And for chrome too I believe.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@media print
{

body, html{
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    min-height:100%;
}
#lines{
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
#footer{
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 20px; 
    left: 4px; 
    right: 4px;
}
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="lines">

 //main content here


</div>

<div id="footer">
//Footer content
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In my case I had a long php file which changed the content dynamically everytime and so I wasnt sure if this solution will always work. So I created a body.php with my main content and footer.php with footer content. Then created another php in the format of the above mentioned solution and included the body.php inside the 'lines' div and footer.php in the 'footer' div. Works well. You will have to adjust the padding to 'lines div'

Answer (score 1):

If you have an long page the footer will be printed on the last page automatically. 
If you want to customize for print you can use a special css-file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

This will be used for printing only and you can use it just like a normal css file.

Comment: Or in an already-existing stylesheet: `@media print{ styles }`. Easier to mantain one file IMO.

Comment: It is printing in the last page. But not on the bottom of the last page. I did use '@media' and made the footer fixed for print out, but that way the footer shows up on bottom of every printed out page, on top of other contents :(

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the styles.. Note that the `html5` elements aren't yet supported by all the browsers. So attach `ids/classes` with the elements and assign custom styles to it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Testing</title> 
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      body { height: 11in;  width: 8.5in; }
      #footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
    </style> 
  </head> 
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        <table>
          more divs... more content...
        </table>
        <table>
          more divs... more content...
        </table>
        ....
    </div>    
    <div id="footer"> 
      This will always print at the bottom
    </div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Note I have added styles for print media only:

```
<style type="text/css" media="print">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      body { height: 11in;  width: 8.5in; }
      #footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
</style>
```

Comment: Just tested this. A good solution when for one printed page. But when the content gets long and goes for several print outs, the footer will stay on the bottom of the first page only...